# Alt codes in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 3 are displayed correct [alt codes](http://www.alt-codes.net/):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> — `♥`
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> — `•`
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> — `☼`

But incorrect:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> — `☺`
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> — `☻`
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> — `♥`

How to me to learn, what alt codes are supported by Sublime Text 3? Whether it is possible to adjust correct display of all alt codes in Sublime Text 3? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Problems - make sure you have numlock on, on your keyboard :)

Comment: @KeithHall: Yes, the reason of incorrect results in disabled `Num Lock`. Please, mark the comment as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>alt</kbd> codes are typically controlled by the OS, and not the software.

If you turn on input logging in the Sublime console (`View` menu -> `Show Console`, `sublime.log_input(True)`), you can see what keys sublime registers when you enter those alt codes.

When typing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, you should get:

- `key evt: alt+keypad1`
- `key evt: alt+keypad4`
- `chr evt: ♫ (0x266b)`

if you get:

- `key evt: alt+end`
- `key evt: alt+left`
- `chr evt: ☺ (0x263a)`

then it means that your <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key is turned off. It needs to be on to enter <kbd>alt</kbd> codes, because they rely on the numeric keys. When Num Lock is on, it normally shows with a light on the keyboard.

See [wikip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Problems) for more details.